# Using Permill in the ink! contract

Tags: ink, smart-contract

I'm writing a chain-extension for a substrate pallet and one of the pallet's functions takes an input parameter which has type `Permill`.
What would be the way to call such function from the contract/chain-extension?

```
pub fn mint_nft(
          // ---- snip ----

            royalty: Option<Permill>,

        ) -> DispatchResult {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm experimenting, u32 works for it. In above example,

```
royalty: Option<u32>,
```

on ink! smart contract side.

If you look at Permill macro, `u32` is used (at the third bottom arg of `implement_per_thing_with_perthousand` macro) for its type.

```
implement_per_thing_with_perthousand!(
    Permill,
    test_permill,
    test_permill_extra,
    [u32, u64, u128],
    1_000_000u32,
    u32,
    u64,
    "_Parts per Million_",
);
```

I also confirmed, if `u32` value is more than million 1000000, decoding will fail on chainextension side.

[macro definition](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/744eda47f545e31083ee722abb3a286f91a7f98d/primitives/arithmetic/src/per_things.rs#L1841)